# How I use post method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

when I submit one page to another, the sites shows the information!
Someone told me to use post to avoid it. however, when I use post method it doesn't work.

```
<form action="\look\at", method="post">
Select your new car's color.
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radios1" value="red">red
<input type="radio" name="radios1" value="green">green
<input type="radio" name="radios1" value="blue">blue
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When I submit I can not see `\look\at` page. but I delete `method="post"` It works well.
How I use post method?

Comment: Did you even tried to open the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)?

Comment: then delete method="post" ;)

Comment: And where are you using ruby on rails in this question? The url looks wrong (write `/look/at`), this is just plain html. Did you write the controller for `look` ? Where is the routing? (it could block a post). And yes: you should use post for forms.

Comment: @nathanvda In controller I put variables to pass the value, and in routes I just wrote get "look/at" that's all. I think routes block post. how shoul I do to routes to use post?

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes (in `config/routes.rb`).

Probably you will have a line

```
get '/look/at', to: 'look#at'
```

replace `get` by `post` and it will accept a post.

Since you are not using the rails form helper or view mechanism (erb/haml) (please start using them, why write plain html????), you have to skip the authenticity token check (please note that this check is there for a reason: it is a protection against cross-site request forgery).

Just add the following line at the top of your controller:

```
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: I tried. post '/look/at'. to: 'look#at' but it doesn't work. the error massage is "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in LookController#at"